# How To Apply Warping Technique for UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image-processing

Currently I am working on Image Processing. I found some warping algorithm techniques. I don't know to apply the techniques in UIImage. Guys If u know that show me the correct route to achieve.
Here is the equation I found: [image]

Comment: Do you mean *wrapping* or perhaps *warping* ?

Comment: I'm willing to bet you wanted P(x) and P(y) too (or, ideally, something other than P for the second one, since it seems to rely on different constants, making it a different function), rather than two P(x)s. That said, what do you want these functions to do? Do you want to plot at each (x, y) the source pixel from (P(x), P(y))?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform affine transformations using [CGAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html).